# Jeep Wrangler's speedometer maximizes at 160 km/h, Toyota Sienna 180. Why are speedometers in smaller cars even higher?

Tags: speedometer

[Jeep Wrangler's speedometer maximizes at 160 km/h](https://reddit.com/r/cars/comments/t2rkf2/unnecessarilyhigh_speedometer_top_speeds/hypnhow)

[image]

[and Toyota Sienna 180](https://reddit.com/r/cars/comments/t2rkf2/unnecessarilyhigh_speedometer_top_speeds/hyoc1v4).

[image]

Then why are speedometers even higher, in small sedans that cannot reach these illegal speeds > 180? My Kia speedometer speeds to 240, but my three-cylinder 1.0L engine definitely cannot!

[image]

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10384
https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/74485
do not answer this question.

Comment: Where do you live that you think speeds above 180 km/h are illegal?

Comment: @Loong 113 kph is illegal everwhere in the United Kingdom. But in Germany some sections of autobahn have no speed limit, others have advisory 130 kph.

Comment: This appears to be from a well known user throughout SE who posts nonsensical questions using fake emails (gmail accounts). They are known as "NNOX Apps" and many other usernames. Currently it's the name shown as the OP here. They just recently created this account then deleted one of their other accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a standard fitment as with many other parts. They use the same instrument cluster for the higher spec versions too.

It reduces manufacturing costs by not having unique parts for every vehicle. On the bigger scale, they share the same engines across different model ranges.

When I bought a replacement door mirror for my Skoda Octavia, it was labelled for the smaller VW Polo – both vehicles from the VAG stable.